# How to simply convert animated GIF to canvas?

Tags: ajax, animation, canvas, gif, loader

I have a problem with webkit browsers - they do not display previews of generated animations on [Preloaders.net](http://preloaders.net). I heard about canvas library, searched through the web, but did not quite understand if I can simply convert animated GIF to canvas, so that it's displayed properly. Does anyone know how I can get the downloaded animated GIF image and make canvas display it with no parameters lost (animation speed, transparency etc)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple way to do this.
you need to get every image of your GIF and then paint it to a canvas.
I recommend those 2 links

http://blog.somepixels.net/2010/01/gif2tileset-extract-gif-frames-into-a-tile-set/ (code is on github)

http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/40515.aspx

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

You cannot display a GIF image on canvas.

Comment: I don't need there to be a GIF, I need an animation preview as if it was a GIF